# PyQt and Python 2.5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Is there a way to install PyQt to make it work with Python 2.5? I searched for PyQt-Py2.5-gpl-4.4.2-1.exe as suggested under http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/01/how-to-install-pyqt-41-python-25-and-qt_8340/ but the link is no longer available within https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can download PyQt4.9.4:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.9.4/